# SQL Server Management Requirments

Tags: sql-server, sql

What is the requirements for latest version of [SQL Server Management Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)? Does it work over Windows 7 X64 or like Sql Server 2016, at least it needs windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft outlined the requirements for SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) on the same [page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) you mentioned (or [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) as well) as:

```
Supported Operating systems

This release of SSMS supports the following platforms when used with the latest available service pack:
Windows 10, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 7 (SP1), Windows Server 2012 (64-bit), Windows Server 2012 R2 (64-bit), Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)
```

So Windows 7 SP1 should be fine to run the SQL Server Management Studio 2016 (the [MS SQL Server Management Studio (16.5.3)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=840946) can be downloaded [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=840946) by the way).

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on Windows 7, but I always have difficulty installing it.  At some point, the installation routine will freeze, and then I have to reboot and start over.  It completes normally on the second try.  This has happened to me at least three times.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the Supported hardware:**
1.8 GHz or faster x86 (Intel, AMD) processor. Dual-core or better recommended
2 GB of RAM; 4 GB of RAM recommended (2.5 GB minimum if running on a virtual machine)
Hard disk space: Minimum of 2 GB up to 10 GB of available space